# JetBrains PhpStorm highlights font-face TTF formatting as wrong

Tags: phpstorm, font-face

I've included a font in my site in `.woff`, `.woff2` and `.ttf` formats. I'm using `truetype` as the format for the `.ttf`

Though the code does compile, PhpStorm marks the syntax as incorrect.

My code is:

```
src: url('assets/icomoon.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('assets/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
          url('assets/icomoon.ttf') format ('truetype');
```

Here's what PhpStorm is doing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
format ('truetype')
```

There should be **no space** between `format` and `(`.

---

**P.S.**
You can also test your code here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Variant with space produces error while the same with no space shows all green.